# CodeIgniter: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, codeigniter

Maybe it's a dumb question.
I'm trying to learn codeigniter and got this error:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

I'm pretty sure that i got this error on the if statement:

```
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Isn't that if statement will return **TRUE** if there is at least "1" or "more than 1" user exist on **users** table?

When I move the foreach code into the else statement, which is like this:

```
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {

} else {
    foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
    }
```

The web successful running and echoing all the users, why is this happen?
Why the if statement return **FALSE**?

Comment: This is the correct way of testing for empty result. What is the result when you echo $q->num_rows() ? What version of CI are you using ,what Database and what driver ?

Comment: @agop the result is invalid argument supplied for foreach(). I'm using the latest version of CI, and the database that I use is **ODBC**. Oh, now I remember that ODBC will return **-1** if the result is true? is this the problem?

Comment: Yes, it might be a CI issue. You can work around it using count($resultset); You might want to report the bug to CI team, and see what they will say.

Comment: @agop thanks for reminding me about the database!